# How do you acquire a Silver or Gold coin in Operation Phoenix?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

How do you acquire a Silver or Gold coin in Operation Phoenix?

[image: Operation Phoenix Silver and Gold coins]

Comment: Do you mean the one that you display or the one that is an achievement. Because the one that you display comes from when you actually buy the operation phoenix pack. That is a gold coin that you can showcase to others in game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is based on how many competitive matches you win, and hours spent in both Competitive and Casual servers (Official Valve servers only!)

- Bronze: 0 hours - 0 wins on Operation Phoenix maps.
- Silver: 10 hours - 5 Competitive wins on Operation Phoenix maps.
- Gold: 30 hours - 15 Competitive wins on Operation Phoenix maps.

From [wiki](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Operation_Bravo_Coin).

Comment: @Sickest all Operation "x" coins have the same scalability.  Meaning, the first Operation Bravo had the same requirements as the second Operation Bravo, as well as this Operation, Phoenix.

Comment: @Lobbe You must play on Valve Competitive servers.  Yes, this means matchmaking, not joining a server with comp mode and a phoenix map enabled.